# maven goal using default maven repo and not the configured one

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, evosuite

I am trying to integrate evosuite in my maven project using instructions from [here](http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/maven-plugin/) and [here](http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/tutorial-part-2/).

I can build the project (clean install) without any issue.
I can execute `evosuite:help` or `evosuite:prepare` goal without any issue.

However I am having issue with `evosuite:generate` goal. There is problem downloading the transitive dependency.

We are using our own central repository which have all the jars that evosuite or evosuite plugin needs yet I can see in the logs that `evosuite:generate` goal tries to connect to default maven central repo `(repo.maven.apache.org)`
instead of the repo that I have configured.

For example;
I have following configuration in my paren pom :

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray-plugins</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

So when I execute `clean install`, it downloads jars from `jcenter.bintray.com`

```
Downloading: http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
Downloaded: http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom (4 KB at 3.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom
Downloaded: http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom (13 KB at 20.7 KB/sec)
```

But while execute `evosuite:generate` it downloads some artifacts from repo.maven
Why is that? How can I force it to refer our custom repo (jcenter in above example)
[Here](https://github.com/niksai/files/blob/master/jcenter_goal_generate.log) is complete logs for same.

Executing in debug mode, I saw a warning that

```
The pom for <name> is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available
```

I have deleted the .m2 folder, checked the jars, downloaded the jars manually and refer them via local url in pom. But it did not solve the issue.

The goals executes fine when you execute from an environment where there are no proxies or other network restriction.
Hence I believe If I am able to use our repo instead of maven default one when goal `evosuite:generate` executes, I might be able to solve the issue.

**Note**: I dont think there's any issue with setting.xml
It has all the configuration for proxy and to use our own artifactory.